# How to ignore Codec after using it to limit size bytes

Tags: scala, shapeless, scodec

I would create a model for the KMIP protocols that works with TTLV encoding ([Tag, Type, Length, Value](http://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/spec/v1.4/os/kmip-spec-v1.4-os.html#_Toc490660911))

The `ttlv` function is "high level" and accepts the tag, the type and the codec of the value.

```
 def ttlv[A<:HList](tag:ByteVector, itype:ByteVector, value: Codec[A]) =
   constant(tag) :: constant(itype) :: 
   (uint32 >>:~ {
     case length => limitedSizeBytes(length, value)
   })
```

The result is a `Codec[Unit :: Unit :: Long :: A]`. However, I would have a `Codec[Unit :: Unit :: Unit :: A]` (or `Codec[A]`) to cast the codec to a `case class` with only the value `A`. How to ignore the `uint32` after used by `limitedSizeBytes` ? Otherwise I am interested for comments for better approaches.

---

Here are `case class` examples:

```
case class RequestHeader(protocol:Int)
case class RequestPayload(payload:CompromiseDate, name:CertificateName)
case class RequestMessage(header:RequestHeader, payload: RequestPayload)
case class CompromiseDate(value:Int)
case class CertificateName(value:String)
```

More high level functions like `ttlvStructure`

```
def ttlvStructure[A<:HList](tag:ByteVector, struct:Codec[A]) =
  ttlv(tag, hex"01", struct)
def ttlvTextString(tag:ByteVector) =
  ttlv(tag, hex"07", utf8.hlist)
def ttlvInt(tag:ByteVector) =
  ttlv(tag, hex"02", int32.hlist)
```

And the final codec:

```
implicit val certificateNameCodec =
  ttlvTextString(hex"420020").as[CertificateName]

implicit val compromiseDateCodec =
  ttlvInt(hex"420021").as[CompromiseDate]

implicit val requestPayloadCodec =
  ttlvStructure(hex"420003", Codec[CompromiseDate] :: Codec[CertificateName]).as[RequestPayload]

implicit val requestHeaderCodec =
  ttlvInt(hex"420002").as[RequestHeader]

implicit val requestMessageCodec =
  ttlvStructure(hex"420001", Codec[RequestHeader] :: Codec[RequestPayload]).as[RequestMessage]
```

Example of object to encode:

```
val m = RequestMessage(
      RequestHeader(14),
      RequestPayload(
        CompromiseDate(8),
        CertificateName("certificate name")
      )
    )
```

---

**Solution**:

`variableSizeBytesLong` is here to do what I want:

```
def ttlv[A<:HList](tag:ByteVector, itype:ByteVector, value: Codec[A]): Codec[A] =
    (constant(tag) :~>: constant(itype) :~>: variableSizeBytesLong(uint32, value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
val defaultLength: Long = ???

def ttlv[A<:HList](tag:ByteVector, itype:ByteVector, value: Codec[A]): Codec[A] =
  constant(tag) :~>: constant(itype) :~>:
    (uint32 >>:~ (length => limitedSizeBytes(length, value))).xmap[A](_.tail, defaultLength :: _)
```

Comment: But the default length is a variable length. I read through the scodec code and I found the perfect `variableSizeBytesLong` results to a codec `(constant(tag) :~>: constant(itype) :~>: variableSizeBytesLong(uint32, value))`.
Thank you !